# Best way to get a precursor in GW2

Tags: guild-wars-2

For now few weeks I decided to get a Legendary Weapon, all the recipes are pretty simple but yet quite expensive.

- T6 components are easy to find or at a reasonable price.
- Since the last Update (16/03/2015) WvW maps don't count for the map completion, So I have the [Gift Of Exploration](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Exploration).
- Bloodstone shards costs 200 skill points, [Obsidian shards](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Obsidian_Shard) are pretty hard to get but playing a bit PVP WvW every day and i got them.
- Other components are easily affordable.

The most important thing to get a Legendary weapon is to get a [Precursor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Precursor), and the only way to get one is using four weapons of the same weapon type guarantees receiving a weapon with that weapon type. For example, players can combine one level 60 rare weapon and three level 80 weapons. Player research into the chance of receiving a precursor when combining four exotic weapons of the same type estimates the probability at 0.79% with 2901 trials.

I have tried a lot, spending a lot of money but nothing.. So I was wondering if there was other ways to get a Precursor because I can't get one with the [MF](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge), and I can't save enough money to buy it in the [BLTC](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Trading_Company).

So, are there other ways to get a Precursor?

Comment: Short answer: farm gold and buy one. No matter how expensive they seem (Dusk peaked at around 1650g but has come down to a bit over 1000g at the time of writing), chances that you'll get the precursor you want from a random drop or from using the Mystic Toilet are so low that buying one from someone who got the drop but wanted the money more than the precursor is just easier. At least statistically speaking. Also, not sure why you say Obsidian Shards are hard to get - it's just karma. And don't underestimate the cost of other stuff: http://gw2legendary.com/ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply, a precursor is just like any other exotic, except way more rare. Thus any way to get an exotic weapon can get you a precursor if you're lucky.

This include (non exhaustive list) :

- 100% exploration reward of high level maps (Like Orr's maps)
- Killing World Boss
- Opening chests (The higher the map level,  the higher the chance of exotic)
- Etc.

Of course you can still concider buying it at the trading post. The prices vary from 400 to 900 gold depending on the precursor. Getting a legendary is a very end game goal so it's supposed to be neither fast nor easy.

To finish, the coming expansion of Guild Wars 2 will rework the end-game progression. As [stated by Nin Hydrine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210225/best-way-to-get-a-precursor-in-gw2/210229?noredirect=1#comment284526_210229) you will be able to earn "Mastery Point" that can be spent in severay "Mastery Lines". Among those line is  the "Mastery of Legends" line. Upon getting it you will unlock a collection that will allow you to get a specific precursor once completed.

Comment: Actually, the Heart of Thorns extension will introduce Masteries as a new progression system, it will not only be about crafting. Playing past level 80 and completing HoT content will give you Mastery Points that you will be able to spend in Mastery lines, one of which allows you to unlock collections to get a precursor. So you will need to collect points, unlock the "Mastery of Legends" line, and complete the collection. It may be long and tedious, but you will be able to get the precursor you want.

Comment: "Thus any way to get an exotic weapon can get you an exotic if you're lucky." Is the second "exotic" in this sentence supposed to be "precursor"? I don't know about the game so I'm not sure, but it seems like it is a typo.

Comment: @Izzo it is indeed

Comment: To sum up, getting a precursor is only a question of luck?

Comment: @Maxime for now, pretty much yes. That or farming gold :)

Comment: @WizLiz Ok well, guess it's time to farm :) thanks for your answer !

Comment: This answer isn't complete without at least mentioning the mystic forge.

Comment: @Brian Allow me to disagree, I explicitly stated "...any way to get an exotic weapon can get you a precursor if you're lucky.". Thus the mystic forge is implied and I just gave some concrete example. An exhaustive list is meaningless and likely to change over time anyway. Plus the OP mentionned the use of the Mystic forge in his question and ended it with "So, are there other ways to get a Precursor?" which makes mentionning the MF less relevant.

Comment: @WizLiz True, the OP mentions it, but only considers a scenario that makes it less likely to get a precursor. Using exotic weapons has a higher chance than using rares, and using high level weapons has a higher chance. Using 3 level 80 weapons and a level 60 has less of a chance than using 4 level 80 weapons, and much less of a chance than using 4 level 80 exotic weapons. It's also worth mentioning that you can mix weapon types and still get a precursor, but the resulting weapon type will be random. This isn't very helpful if you want a specific pre-cursor, but is if you just plan to sell it.